# Return tuple list in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

How make for return tuple in class

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, value, image):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.image = image

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self.name, self.value, self.image)
```

I to need make insert in MySql witch `executemany`, how are no interator Does not work.

Implements class:

```
from Product import Product

Products = []

Product_name = "Fruit 01"
Product_price = 12.25
Product_image = "src/test.png"

Products.append(Product(
    Product_name,
    Product_price,
    Product_image
))
```

Comment: `__int__` is supposed to return an `int`; did you mean `__iter__`? What exactly do you want to iterate over?

Comment: I have this class that I add values ​​to an array through it, so I need to return the data when it is called in the tuple format accepted by the SQL database.

Comment: Added implementation of class correction `__int__` to `__iter__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__iter__` method should return an iterator.

You can either use the `iter` function to create an iterator from the tuple:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter((self.name, self.value, self.image))
```

or use the `yield from` statement to achieve the same:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from (self.name, self.value, self.image)
```

Comment: this:

`
def __iter__(self):
    yield from (self.name, self.value, self.image)
`

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Return this error

Comment: That error has to come from some other code that you have not posted. Please update your question with your actual code if you need more help.

Comment: I have only these two files open to prevent another location giving error.
I put him here
https://repl.it/repls/PerfectExpensiveBookmark

Comment: You aren't using either of my solutions in the linked code. Also, you should not just iterate over the `products` list, but also iterate over each `Product` object in the list. Example: https://repl.it/repls/WellinformedTurquoiseDeveloper

Comment: Thank you very much,
it worked.
As I was expecting the interaction to occur in the for print and was not occurring. Thank you for your help

Comment: This seems over-engineered to me. just `yield self.name; yield self.value; yield self.image` should work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True. I was kind of bound by the OP's use of a tuple in the question, but yeah, unless the OP has in fact a large number of attributes to yield, 3 `yield` statements would be the simplest in this case.